# Orientation is not Updating After unlock the Device in react-native- android

Tags: react-native

i am Developing one Application, Actually my App is showing landscape and Portrait in Tabs/iPads. But in Tablets(iPad's working fine) when i was check the Orientation functionality working fine until unlock the Device.When i was lock the screen on Particular mode like (Portrait/Landscape) After that turned the Device showing before Orientation. Not Update the present Orientation.

I followed this link :**https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation**

this is my code:

```
componentWillMount(){
this.getOrientationtype()
}

getOrientationtype(){
    //alert("Hello")
    if(Platform.OS == 'ios'){  // to Identifying Android or iOS
     if(aspectRatio>1.6){  // Code for Iphone
       // alert("phone")
        Orientation.lockToPortrait()
       }
       else{
         Orientation.getOrientation((err, initial) => {
          if(initial != 'UNKNOWN'){
            this.setState({
              orientation:initial
            }) 
          }
          else{
            this.setState({
              orientation:'PORTRAIT'
            })
          }
        });

       }
     }
     else{

     if(DeviceInfo.isTablet()){
         // alert("android tab")
         Orientation.getOrientation((err, initial) => {
          if(initial != 'UNKNOWN'){
            this.setState({
              orientation:initial
            }) 
          }
          else{
            this.setState({
              orientation:'PORTRAIT'
            })
          }
        });
      }
      else{
        Orientation.lockToPortrait()
      }
     }
  }
```

Please find Out this Solution ....I am Using this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You should use `Orientation.addOrientationListener` for listen to the [Orientation Events](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#orientation-events).

2.As see from the source code of [OrientationModule.java](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/github/yamill/orientation/OrientationModule.java#L161), this library just call `unregisterReceiver` in `onHostPause`, so you can't receive `onConfigurationChanged` event after lock the screen.One way is to edit the `onHostResume` inside [OrientationModule.java](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/github/yamill/orientation/OrientationModule.java#L161) to meet what you want.

```
@Override
public void onHostResume() {
    final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

    if (activity == null) {
        FLog.e(ReactConstants.TAG, "no activity to register receiver");
        return;
    }
    activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("onConfigurationChanged"));
    //add below code to onHostResume function
    //send broadcast onResume
    final int orientationInt = getReactApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
    newConfig.orientation = orientationInt;
    Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
    intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
    activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

the whole code can be found here [OrientationModule.java](https://pastebin.com/1ry7gZrQ)